# Miglayout cc.gapX results only in null-values

Tags: miglayout

I'm trying to update gapBefore of a component in a miglayout.

```
CC cc = getCC(currentElement);
System.out.println("Constraint before: " + IDEUtil.getConstraintString(cc, false));     
String before = "10px:20lp:30%"; String after = null;
cc.gapX(before, after);
System.out.println("Constraint after: " + IDEUtil.getConstraintString(cc, false));
```

Console: "Constraint before: cell 0 0,grow"
Console: "Constraint after: cell 0 0,gapx null:null:null,grow"

---

What is wrong? Do I need to update the constraint?

BTW: I know, that it is easier to set the constraint static in the layout. In my case I need to do this dynamically, using the constraints from a textbox.

I'm using ideutil-4.2

Comment: It seems to be the same with cc.minWidth() and other methods from the api-Functions. Everytime the constraint is built with the keyword like "wmin " and a "null"-value. I have no idea how to solve this problem.